# gRaphael : how to avoid space between barchart()

Tags: jquery, svn, raphael, graphael

is there any option to avoid space between barchart in Raphaël ?

There is an option to mange bar space, unfortunately `gutter` option is effecting the width of the bar. Sadly I have not enough points to upload an image :(

here is my code

```
var efficiency = Raphael("overview");
efficiency.barchart(0, 210, 150, 90, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 10], [10, 5, 32, 13, 2, 55, 8]], {stacked: true, colors:["#F58A2A", "#D4D4D4"], "gutter":"50%"});
```

demo - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/R52e3/)

any help much appreciated 
thanks

Comment: If you include a jsfiddle of your code helping would be easier!

Comment: @Trufa thank for you interest on solving this issue. Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/R52e3/

Answer (score 3):

When zero isn't small enough , use negative :)

like this:

```
"gutter":"-1%"
```

Here is a fiddle : [BarChart no space](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/v7XBD/)